# Умение(,) невзирая ни на что(,) достичь компромисса(,) где бы то ни было — это важно

Tags: запятые

Нужны какие-то запятые?

> Умение(,) невзирая ни на что(,) достичь компромисса(,) где бы то ни было — это важно.

Comment: Теперь и у меня вопрос появился. Известно, что деепричастие / деепричастный оборот может тесно примыкать только к глаголу. А работает ли это с оборотом с _несмотря на_? Или такой оборот к любому члену может примыквть? В вашем случае к определению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ на комментарий**

```
 Мне кажется, что, т. к. где бы то ни было значит 'везде, в 
 любом месте', не нужна запятая.
```

Сложный вопрос, пока могу предложить **такую информацию.**

1. **[Справочник  по пунктуации](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE&mode=all)** 
   КАК БЫ ТАМ / ТО НИ БЫЛО, вводное сочетание.
2. Итак, это вводное предложение, поэтому **обособляется**.  Грамматика такова, что затруднительно считать иначе и приравнивать выражение к устойчивому сочетанию.
3. У **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)** самое близкое: Пункт 8. Сочетания *кто ни на есть, что ни на есть, какой ни на есть* и т. п. запятыми не выделяются.
4. С другой стороны, необособленный вариант встречается: **[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D1%8B+%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE).** Но там особые конструкции, где возможен переход в наречное сочетание, например:

*Завтра, послезавтра и в последующие дни я снова ныряю в студёную, без преувеличения, морскую глубину, и опять же с головкой, поскольку именно так люблю плавать **где бы то ни было.***

5. Думаю, что в заданном предложении нет такой тесной связи, поэтому лучше **обособить** как вводное сочетание по справочнику.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*Умение **(какое?)** **невзирая ни на что** (= любой ценой) достичь компромИсса, **где бы то нИ было** — это вАжно.*

1. ***Невзирая ни на что*** — словосочетание использовано в значении наречия в составе несогласованного **определения**, выраженного **инфинитивом**. Здесь нет паузы.

Сравнить: *Умение, **любой ценой**, достичь...*  Это некорректное употребление наречия.

2. ***Где бы то ни было*** — придаточное предложение.

**Примеры из литературы:**

*Время показушной крутости и игры на публику прошло, наступили суровые времена, когда в большой цене реальная сила и способность **(какая?)** **невзирая ни на что** бросить вызов даже самому сильному противнику и победить его…*

*Чтобы доверить себя незнакомым людям, нужны очень большая воля **(какая?)** **невзирая ни на что** попасть в их среду, а также определённая (и немалая) степень доверия этим людям.*

Comment: Перед тире запятая, завершающая придаточное, нужна, т. к. сказуемое относится к слову _умение_, а придаточное их не связывает, поэтому с двух сторон обособить нужно.

Comment: Я решаю задачу по Лопатину (сложная конструкция, проблемные запятые). В этом случае (при постановке запятой) у меня получится единый знак, а он здесь неуместен. Надо видеть всю конструкцию, а не решать ее по частям методом рассуждений. Читатель хочет видеть готовый результат, удобный для понимания смысла.  Это именно то, что ему нужно.  А рассуждения могут быть разными. Вот и автор не поставил запятую.

Comment: Умение любой цной достичь компромисса во всем - это важно.  Это конечный результат.  На границе блоков мы видим тире.

Comment: Мне кажется, что, т. к. *где бы то ни было* значит 'везде, в любом месте', не нужна запятая.